Actress auditions with a very different read
I recall a scene in a movie which involves auditions for a female part.
The casting man plays the candidate's boss(?) or lover(?) and the scene involves the female being very angry with the male; at least, that's how most auditioners play it - all fury and rage.
Until this one candidate turns the very same script into a very sexy, breathy reading which is a huge come-on to the male, and gets him rather hot under the collar. (Phrases like "you are a despicable man" - use your imagination!)
What movie is this? I have a (weak) feeling it's from the 90s, possibly 80s.

This sounds a lot like the audition scene in David Lynch's Mulholland Dr. but it's from 2001.

After a car wreck on the winding Mulholland Drive renders a woman amnesiac, she and a perky Hollywood-hopeful search for clues and answers across Los Angeles in a twisting venture beyond dreams and reality.

Naomi Watts' character auditions for a part where she's supposed to play a woman angry with her father's friend, but when she's at the audition, she suddenly chooses to play it seductively. You can see the original rehearsal and then the audition scene here:




This is almost certainly it. Lynch's somewhat unusual style, plus the deliberate mixing and blurring of various eras within the film itself is probably what made it seems like it could have been from the 80s or 90s. Solid answer! :)

Brilliant! Yes, that's the one - thank you very much. I had no recall that I'd even seen Mulholland Drive! I wanted it to show my 15-yr old daughter, who is currently auditioning, and we were talking about the range of readings possible. Cheers :-)
